# manipulating ndarray dimension with function and adding new data to it

Tags: function, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm using this to control the color scale on a fractal drawing program. I was wondering if there was a way to eliminate the r,g,b variable and insert the result right into the img ndarray? I have fiddled with adding a new dimension with np.expand_dims, but the shape turns into (5,5,1) instead of (5,5,3) like I need. reshaping it seems to be a nightmare.

```
import numpy as np
#img is an array of values to be converted into RGB from another process
img = np.arange(25)
img = np.reshape(img,(5,5))

#simplified example of original process
r = img*2
g = img*3
b = img*4

#creating new array to accomidate the higher dimension
img = np.array([r,g,b], dtype = np.uint8)

#no longer needed
del r,g,b

#rolling axis for PIL Image.fromarray compatibily
img = np.rollaxis(img,0,3)
img = np.rollaxis(img,0,2)
print(img)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`img` starts as a (5,5) array.  That's one value for each of the 25 pixels.

The new array after joining the `r,g,b` arrays is (3,5,5).

The first rollaxis changes that into a (5,5,3) array.

```
np.stack([r,g,b], axis=2)
```

would have done the same.

The second rollaxis swaps the first two dimensions, in effect transposing the original image. (in fact both `rollaxis` could be replaced with one `img.transpose()`.

Even when you use `expand_dims` you still make a new array (though it does share the databuffer with the original).  But (5,5,1) still doesn't have space to store the 3 color values.  The original has 25 values, the new image has 75.  You have to make a new array in one way or the other.

To better understand the `rollaxis` part, I suggest playing with an array like

```
arr = np.arange(24).reshape(3,2,4)
```

different sizes in all 3 dimensions make it easier to see the changes in shape.

Comment: Thanks! I'm very new to Numpy. Your method tips are very helpful.